# i have stored a data in firebase realtime database via android app.how could i retrieve the saved data from the website

Tags: javascript, android

I have stored the data in firebase realtime database

My android piece of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef,demoRef; 
rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
demoRef = rootRef.child("demo");      
demoRef.push().setValue(value);
```

I tried to retrieve this saved data from website.
I have also included the script from firebase which has api key,project id etc.,

```
var tblUsers = document.getElementById('tbl_users_list');
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('demo/');
function retrieve_user(){
var updates ={};
updates['/demo/' + ... ] = ....;
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
reload_page();
}
```

Comment: What is an error?

Comment: Just blank...I cant retrieve the data..but retrieval from the android app is possible